# Wifi does not wake up when using Hybrid suspend in Ubuntu 14.04.2

Tags: wireless, suspend, hibernate

I am trying to use Hybrid suspend in Ubuntu 14.04.2 . While the suspend and resume works, the wifi and the networking breaks every time.
Running /etc/init.d/networking restart or service networking restart/start/stop does not get the network back.

Any idea how to get this working?

```
lspci | grep -i network
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter

uname -a
Linux flex2 3.16.0-31-generic #41~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Feb 11 19:30:13 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS"
```

Answer (score 2):

My solution is to create an executable script that connects my computer to wifi/lan after suspend. The script name and folder is `/etc/systemd/system/net-resume.service`, with the following contents:

```
[Unit]
Description=Local system resume actions
After=suspend.target
[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/systemctl restart network-manager.service
[Install]
WantedBy=suspend.target
```

Then run the command:

```
sudo systemctl enable net-resume.service
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to deactivate then reactivate only the wireless connection as described here : https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/power-nowireless.html

If you want to do it via commands, instead of restarting `networking` try restarting `network-manager`.

I get the same trouble as you on 15.04 (appears after upgrading) on a macbookpro10,1.